# NHibernate Cached Query

Tags: nhibernate, caching

I want to have this cached query in NHibernate:

```
Configuration configurationEntry = session.CreateQuery("from Configuration configurationEntry where configurationEntry.Name = 'DefaultVendorId'").SetCacheable(true).UniqueResult<Configuration>();
```

I have

```
<property name="cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
```

in the NHibernate configuration file.

However, when I run the NHibernate profiler I see that NHibernate executes the query multiple times .. I obviously want the query executed only once and the result cached. Any ideas ?

Regards,
MadSeb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope its the same as in Java Hibernate....you have to add a linkage to your cache provider...because Hibernates provides none...

This is part of my Java-Hibernate configuration that links cache provider.

```
            <prop key="hibernate.cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
```